# Group_Concat and Inner Join

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have a query that I wrote but trying to refer to another table in the `group_concat()` function and not quite sure how to do it.  Have tried quite a few ways and only get errors.

Here is the working query:

```
SELECT StyleID, 
       StyleName, 
       ItemID, 
       Sizes, 
       Prices, 
       Stock, 
       OtherDetails,
      (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Styles.ItemID ORDER BY Styles.ItemID SEPARATOR '|')
       FROM Styles) ItemList 
FROM Styles 
ORDER BY ItemID ASC
```

ItemList comes back with the desired result:

```
9|13|14|16|17
```

What I want to do is to have the name that comes with the id returned that is in another table (Categories) like:

```
9~T-Shirts|13~Tanks....etc.
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: You would have to add a `JOIN` into your subquery, then do `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Styles.ItemID,'~',category ORDER BY ...)`.

Comment: I tried that, and got errors.  Can you give me an example?

Comment: *What* errors did you get?  What was the query you tried?  It can be as simple as `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Styles.ItemID,'~',category) FROM Styles JOIN Categories USING(catID)` (or whatever your fields are named).

Comment: SELECT StyleID, StyleName, ItemID, Sizes, Prices, Stock, OtherDetails, Categories.categoryName, Categories.categoryID, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Styles.ItemID, '~', Categories.categoryName ORDER BY Styles.ItemID SEPARATOR '|')FROM Styles) ItemList FROM Styles JOIN Categories USING(Categories.categoryID) ORDER BY ItemID ASC

Error Returned:
 Unknown column 'Categories.categoryID' in 'from clause'

Comment: When you use the `USING()` keyword, you *don't* use the table name.  `JOIN Categories USING(categoryID)`, assuming both `Styles` and `Categories` have a `categoryID` field.

Comment: The categoryName comes up the same all the way through, for example:

9~T-Shirts|13~T-Shirts|14~T-Shirts|15~T-Shirts|16~T-Shirts|17~T-Shirts

Should be:
9~T-Shirts|13~Men's Tanks|14~Women's Tanks|.....

Comment: You may need a `GROUP BY Styles.ItemID` or `GROUP BY Categories.categoryID` in there.